# Excel lookup based on multiple criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: explanation]

[image: real data]

I have the following problem: need to lookup for data based on 3 criteria:

1. Product type - Exact match
2. Product Height - loose values in ranges
3. Product Width - same as above.

I have a multiple tables like D3:I8 with cost of used components based on maximum product width&height for that range. in example 0 emerge on the intersection it means that product cant be constucted (width, height or both too large). we can make 2250mm x 700mm but 2250 x 1000 is impossible to make since 0. Those are only example datas in reality those numbers for width and height are diffrent.

Please can someone guide me through this problem?

(picture is worth more than a thousand words)

Comment: Do the different tables have the same number of rows and columns? Also: what version of Excel? 365 can do a lot more than 2019 or 2016 or earlier.

Comment: nope unfortunately not. i just checked that and it seems to have causing issues with the solutions provided by teylyn

Comment: I added additional screenshot this time with real data tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the tables are always 6 rows x 6 columns, you can use Let() in 365 or just Offset in older versions.

Using Office 365 with the new Let() Function

```
=LET(myTable,INDEX(D:D,MATCH(L5,B:B,0)):INDEX(I:I,MATCH(L5,B:B,0)+6),INDEX(myTable,MATCH(M5,OFFSET(myTable,0,0,6,1),1),MATCH(N5,OFFSET(myTable,0,0,1,6),1)))
```

[image]

Or, if you don't have the Let() function, use this ugly compilation of Offset repeats:

```
=INDEX(OFFSET(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(L5,B:B,0)),0,2,6,6),MATCH(M5,OFFSET(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(L5,B:B,0)),0,2,6,1),1),MATCH(N5,OFFSET(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(L5,B:B,0)),0,2,1,6),1))
```

**Edit**: if the tables all have different shapes, then you may want to take the trouble of selecting each table and assigning them range names with the name manager, like "Type1", "Type2" etc.  In the screenshot below I have the following range names:

```
Type1   ='Sheet1 (2)'!$D$3:$I$8
Type2   ='Sheet1 (2)'!$D$10:$G$18
Type3   ='Sheet1 (2)'!$D$20:$L$26
```

With these range names in place, you can use this formula:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Type"&L5),MATCH(M5,OFFSET(INDIRECT("Type"&L5),0,0,ROWS(INDIRECT("Type"&L5)),1),1),MATCH(N5,OFFSET(INDIRECT("Type"&L5),0,0,1,COLUMNS(INDIRECT("Type"&L5))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: thank you for your solution. unfortunately it does not solve my problem because of diffrent dimensions of the "price based on dimension" tables. i didnt know it beforehand and wanted to try this on a living tables and they are very diverse between 2 and 15 rows and between 2 and 15 columns

Comment: I added additional screenshot this time with real data tables

Comment: I added another approach to my answer.

Comment: Im gonna check that in few hours. thanks for the help.

Comment: it took longer than i expected - was sick for a few days. it's working almost perfect (with named ranges) but it should give results to the table width and height not from eg.

In the 3rd type i have in the first post should return following: (W/H/expected result)

Comment: ignore the latter answer please - i had error in matrix in this example.